# compare 2 files with arithmetic using awk command

Tags: linux, awk, compare

I have 2 files:

File 1

```
*Name|Date|id|Total*
Jimmy|03-OCT-18|BST100114262|20000
Dedi|03-OCT-18|BST100904288|10000
```

File 2

```
*Name|Amount*
Anton|9800
Jimmy|90000
```

Output :
*Jimmy|20000|90000|1800000000*

I've tried, but no luck.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1; next} (($1 in a) && (a[$4] >= $2 )) { print a[$4]*$2 }'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown samples of input and output in code tags. Could you please let us know how come `1800000000` is coming in output? Kindly explain it.

Comment: 1800000000 come from total of jimmy at file 1, multiple by amount of jimmy at file 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}($1 in a)&&FNR>1{print $1,a[$1],$NF,a[$1]* $NF}{a[$1]=$NF}' file1 file2
```

outputs:

```
Jimmy|20000|90000|1800000000
```

Explained some using Jimmies:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }               # set separators
($1 in a) && FNR>1 {               # if key to hash (Jimmy) is in a excluding headers
    print $1,a[$1],$NF,a[$1]* $NF  # process Jimmy
    # next                         # this excludes new Jimmy from being rehashed to a
}
{
    a[$1]=$NF                      # ... in here where everything is hashed and  the
}' file1 file2                     # ... existing rehashed
```

Comment: Thanks James, It's helpful. how do I combine if FNR<1 then devide by another ?

Comment: FNR cannot be <1, it's the row number of the file - well I guess in theory it could be 0 for an empty file but I doubt that. `* ` for multiplication, `/` for division.

Comment: actually I'm looking for the same name and compare it. In this case I have Jimmy. If total of Jimmy in file 1 greater than amount of jimmy in file 2 and then multiple it

Comment: You should add an example to the OP to clarify that requirement.